# How to build a dynamic array in C++ and return it back to C#/.NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arrays, winapi

I have to find the way to build the array of structs on C++ Win32 side. I don't have the initial number of items. It should be very fast to resize that array.

When the list is build, I need to return it back to .NET. So That array(list) should be converted to the transport which easily can be read on .NET side or the initial list can be used "as is" just passing the pointer.

Thanks in advance for giving me a hint!

Comment: In C++ dynamic array = [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Are you P/Invoking or working in C++/CLI? For C++/CLI you can just `gcnew` an `Array` or `List` and be done.

Comment: @crashmstr I created standard c++ win32 library. Just Invoking (marshaling). c++ methods via obtaining the pointer to exported method in c++ dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very common way of implementing "dynamic arrays" in C++ is to use STL's **`std::vector`**. In your case, you can define a `vector<SomeData>`. `std::vector` can change its size *dynamically* (i.e. at run-time), as per your request: you can use its `push_back` or `emplace_back` methods for that purpose, adding new items to the vector.

However, C# doesn't "understand" `std::vector`.

To marshal its content to C#, you could use a **`SAFEARRAY`**, which the CLR understands very well. The good thing about SAFEARRAY is that it stores also the array size, besides the array content: it's a self-contained data structure.
So, you can create a SAFEARRAY of proper size, fill it with the content dynamically created in the vector, and pass that SAFEARRAY to C#.

Note that you could also build a SAFEARRAY directly, without passing for std::vector. But STL's vector has a more powerful programming interface; so if you want to do several additions of items via push_back or emplace_back at run-time, building the std::vector first, and then "marshalling" it into a SAFEARRAY, could be a better option. Anyway, that depends on your particular needs and context.

---

As an alternative, you could use C++/CLI as a bridging layer between the C++ side and the C# side. In this case you could use `gcnew` to create a .NET "managed" **`array`**.

---

And, as another option, you could export a couple of functions from your native C++ DLL with a C interface:

- a function to get the count of items in the array
- another function to get the actual array data in an output caller-allocated buffer (the size of which is returned by the previous function)

In C#, the output buffer pointer is passed using an `IntPtr` output parameter.
You can then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to marshal a single data item, and you can increase the pointer using `Marshal.SizeOf`, to make it point to the next item in the array.

Something like this:

```
// In C++:

struct SomeData
{
    /* your data fields */
};

// Export these two functions from your native DLL:
extern "C" int GetSomeDataCount( /* some params */ );
extern "C" void GetSomeData( SomeData* ptr, /* some other params */ );


// In C#:    

public struct SomeData
{
    // Map C++ data structure fields to C#
}

static extern int GetSomeDataCount( /* some params */ );
static extern void GetSomeData( [Out] out IntPtr ptr, /* some other params */ );

SomeData[] GetSomeData( /* some params */ )
{
    // Allocate an array of proper size
    SomeData[] dataArray = new SomeData[ GetSomeDataCount( /* some params */ ) ];

    // Fill the array with content from GetSomeData
    IntPtr dataPtr;
    GetSomeData( out dataPtr, /* some other params */ );
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
    {
        dataArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataPtr, typeof(SomeData));
        dataPtr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeData));
    }
    return dataArray;
}
```

Comment: Is SAFEARRAY the underlying layer for a vector? Can I dig the SAFEARRAY out and pass to c# .NET? Or Should I copy the content of vector to a new created SAFEARRAY?

Comment: @John: I'm not sure about what you exactly mean by SAFEARRAY being the underlying for a vector. std::vector and SAFEARRAY are completely different entities: the former is a C++ standard class template, the latter is a Win32 OLE structure. The .NET's CLR understands SAFEARRAY very well, so it can extract the raw array data from the passed SAFEARRAY. But SAFEARRAY lacks the programming interface versatility and power of std::vector. That's why I suggested to build the dynamic array using std::vector first, and then copy to SAFEARRAY, and use it for marshalling.

Comment: OK, now everything is now clear to me. Thanks again for your tips.

Comment: I have been struggling with creating and passing to c# a SAFEARRAY and it is not working at all :( Could You look at that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011617/return-safearray-from-c-to-c-sharp

Comment: What var Type i should use for a struct?

Answer (score 3):

Generally if your C++ dll compiled with CLI support you can simply use managed containers. If you don't want your dll to be compiled with CLI option, then you may write small C++/CLI wrapper dll which will call methods from native C++ dll and store objects in the managed container. 
Another possible solution is to change interface of the C++ lib to return objects by indexes, support insertion and/or removal.

```
std::vector<CFoo> vec;

void init() {
    //read data to vec
}

CFoo getIthElement(int i) {
    return vec[i];
}

int getElementCount() {
    return vec.size();
}
```

So you will use `getIthElement` and  `getElementCount` functions on the C# side.

Comment: I would like to stay with c++. What do you mean by returning objects by indexes?