# Marshaling strings to unmanaged memory, passing them to c++ and return back to c# again

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am creating unmanaged memory block in c# and fill it with data from structs.

I iterate through the list of structs and do something like this:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(structTemp, currentMemoryPosition, false);
currentMemPosition = new IntPtr(currentMemPosition.ToInt64() + structSize);
```

The struct contains reference type: "string".
I've looked into BOL for a StructureToPtr method and there it says:

```
"All other reference types (for example, strings and arrays) are marshaled to copies"
```

**What exactly does it mean?**

Does it mean that the reference to that string will still be in the memory, in spite of the fact the instance of a struct will go out of scope?

The above unmanaged memory block, I pass to c++ method which makes use of it. When the job is done on c++ part I iterate again through structs in memory (in c#) and:

```
Marshal.DestroyStructure(currentMemPosition, typeof(struct));
```

The most important question for me is:

```
Whether I can:

1) Create structs with strings inside
2) Marshal them to unmanaged mamory
3) Make use of them on c++ side
4) **Return them from c++**
5) Read them again in c#
6) Deallocate them in c# by using Marshal.DestroyStructure (EDITED)
```

The struct layout with string reference type is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
internal struct TempStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 36)]
    private string iuTest;

    public TempStruct(Guid IuTest)
        : this()
    {
        iuTest = IuTest.ToString("D");
    }
}
```

Comment: To read them again in C# you have to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to "copy back" changes done to the copy of the struct created by `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. Point 6 is wrong: You have to deallocate the copy with `Marshal.DestroyStructure`. Note that you then have to free the memory you had allocated for `Marshal.PtrToStructure`

Comment: I don't change the strings on c++ side. Lets say I pass to c++ 5 strings, and c++ returns 2 of them (without touching them)

Comment: How do you return them?

Comment: What is your struct layout, specifically, is the string of fixed size and marshalled as an `LPStr`?

Comment: @xanatos On c++ side c#'s string is mapped to: "char *" That pointer I have planned to returned it back in a new array of structs (returned in a SAFEARRAY) thinking that pointer created for a string in c# I can returned it back from c++

Comment: @aevitas I have reedited the question

Comment: @John Thanks, you should be able to marshal this back and forth between C# and C++ provided you set up some sort of shared memory or named pipe that both the C++ and the C# application can use. The CLR requires structs that get marshalled with a string member to be of fixed size, but it appears you already fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @aevitas So is that correct that Marshaling struct with a string member to unmanaged memory will keep the pointer to a string still in memory, although the instance of a struct will be deallocated when it gets out of scope in c#?

Comment: @John Every time your struct is marshalled, be it from C# to unmanaged or vice-versa, it is copied - reference types are different, they are "dereferenced" and have their value copied. If you keep a pointer to said string in your C++ application and destroy it, you will of course end up with a dangling pointer. On a side note, you should probably be looking at a named pipe if interprocess communication is your goal. It'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "All other reference types (for example, strings and arrays) are marshaled to copies"
>   What exactly does it mean?

The `Marshal.StructureToPtr` creates copies of the `string`. It does it even if you are marshaling to `LPWStr`. This is different from passing parameters to methods, where sometimes strings/arrays aren't copied around but are passed directly.

So after calling `Marshal.StructureToPtr` you now have two copies of your `iuTest`: one in the variable `iuTest`, that is directly managed by .NET (and so that will be deallocated automatically), and one in the copy created by `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. This copy must be destroyed manually, for example with `Marshal.DestroyStructure`.

Note that the `SizeConst = 36` is ignored here, because the exact quantity of memory needed will be allocated by `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.

Full example:

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
internal struct TempStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string iuTest;

    public TempStruct(Guid IuTest)
        : this()
    {
        iuTest = IuTest.ToString("D");
    }
}

[DllImport("NativeLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void TempStructMethod(IntPtr ptr);
```

and then:

```
var str = new TempStruct(Guid.NewGuid());

Console.WriteLine("C# side: {0}", str.iuTest);

// It will be 4 or 8, depending if you are running 32 or 64 bits
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TempStruct));

IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

// Marshaling to ptr
Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, false);

// Call your C++ method
TempStructMethod(ptr);

Console.WriteLine("C# side in original struct: {0}", str.iuTest);

// Marshaling back
str = (TempStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TempStruct));

Console.WriteLine("C# side after marshaled back: {0}", str.iuTest);

// Freeing the "content" of the marshaled struct (the marshaled 
// string in this case)
Marshal.DestroyStructure(ptr, typeof(TempStruct));

// Freeing the memory allocated for the struct object (the 
// "container")
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
```

and C++ (`CoTaskMem*` are in `#include <Objbase.h>`):

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void TempStructMethod(TempStruct *ts)
    {
        printf("C++ side: %s\n", ts->iuTest);

        // If you want to free a C# marshaled string use CoTaskMemFree
        // See in https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/fieldmarshaler.cpp
        // FieldMarshaler_StringAnsi::DestroyNativeImpl and
        // FieldMarshaler_StringUni::DestroyNativeImpl 

        // Here we want to modify the string C-side

        // First we free it
        CoTaskMemFree(ts->iuTest);
        ts->iuTest = NULL;

        char *str = "abcdefab-cdef-abcd-efab-cdefabcdefab";
        int len = strlen(str) + 1;

        // Then we allocate a new string
        // Use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory that can be freed by C#
        ts->iuTest = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc(len);

        // Then we copy our string in the allocated memory
        strcpy(ts->iuTest, str);

        // Note that you could have reused the "original"
        // memory of ts->iuTest in this case, because it
        // was of the "right" size. I freed and reallocated
        // just to show how to do it!
    }
}
```

Result:

```
C# side: d3ccb13c-fdf9-4f3d-9239-8d347c18993c
C++ side: d3ccb13c-fdf9-4f3d-9239-8d347c18993c
C# side in original struct: d3ccb13c-fdf9-4f3d-9239-8d347c18993c
C# side after marshaled back: abcdefab-cdef-abcd-efab-cdefabcdefab
```

C#-side you can even use the `char*` pointer of the marshaled struct... You know that it is at offset 0 of the marshaled struct (because it is the first field), so:

```
IntPtr ptr2 = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, 0); // will read the char* pointer
string str2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr2);
Console.WriteLine("Unmarshaling manually: {0}", str2);
```

(not directly connected to the question, asked in char):

marshalling an array from C# to C++, marshalling back from C++ to C# another array:

C++

```
struct TempStruct
{
    char* iuTest;
};

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void GetSomeData(TempStruct *inPtr, TempStruct **outPtr, int *numPtr)
    {
        // Number of elements we want to return
        *numPtr = 10;

        // Space for these elements
        *outPtr = (TempStruct*)malloc(*numPtr * sizeof(TempStruct));

        for (int i = 0; i < *numPtr; i++)
        {
            TempStruct *curr = *outPtr + i;

            // Here we allocate some space for the char* iuTest
            curr->iuTest = (char*)malloc(10);

            // And we write something on it (in this case the 'i')
            itoa(i, curr->iuTest, 10);
        }
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void FreeSomeData(TempStruct *ptr, int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            TempStruct *curr = ptr + i;

            // First we free the char* iuTest
            free(curr->iuTest);
        }

        // Then we free the ptr
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

C#

```
// Some TempStruct(s) to pass to C++
TempStruct[] someData = new TempStruct[5];

for (int i = 0; i < someData.Length; i++)
{
    someData[i] = new TempStruct(Guid.NewGuid());
}

// C++ will return its TempStruct array in ptr
IntPtr ptr;
int length;

GetSomeData(someData, out ptr, out length);

// This must be equal to C++ sizeof(TempStruct)
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TempStruct));

TempStruct[] someData2 = new TempStruct[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // We marshal back an element of TempStruct
    IntPtr curr = (IntPtr)(ptr + (size * i));
    someData2[i] = (TempStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(curr, typeof(TempStruct));
}

// Important! We free the TempStruct allocated by C++. We let the
// C++ do it, because it knows how to do it.
FreeSomeData(ptr, length);
```

Comment: SizeConst isn't ignored - the call to `StructureToPtr` will fail if the string doesn't have a size constant specified in the `MarshalAs` attribute, this is a CLR requirement you can not work around.

Comment: @aevitas No, you don't. You need it if you want to do a `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`. And it is ignored. I've watched the pointer generated with the `Debug->Windows->Memory`

Comment: It may be ignored but is required by the CLR to be able to obtain a meaningful size for the struct - without it you'd be violating one of the core principles the CLR enforces with regards to structs.

Comment: @aevitas Do you know what is `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`? It means that the struct in C will be `struct MyStruct {char *str;}`, so `sizeof(MyStruct) == sizeof(char*)`, so given 32 or 64 bits, the size of the struct is fixed, for any size of the `str`.

Comment: Oversight on my end - for `LPStr` this requirement is of course implicitly met. I stand corrected.

Comment: @xanatos is PtrToStructure creating a copy of the reference type?

Comment: @John There are no reference types here. `struct` is a value type. And the marshaled struct is an usafe object. `PtrToStructure` copies ("marshals") an unsafe object back to C#. This copy is then copied back to `str` (that is our variable) with an assignment `str = (TempStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: @xanatos I meant, You wrote that: StructureToPtr makes another pointer to a reference type (string) so we've got 2 (c#'s and that passed to c++). So i thought that the pointer created on c++ side, using: PtrToStructure will do the same, create a copy of the string inside that structs. So in the end we will have two ... right?

Comment: @John Yep. `StructureToPtr` doesn't "destroy" the `ptr`, so you'll have two copies.

Comment: Well Ok. As with the SAFEARRAY is a problem, I thought I could try the normal way (@Mr.C64 suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670551/how-to-build-a-dynamic-array-in-c-and-return-it-back-to-c-net) However, when I have already created a reference type i just wanted to use it on both sides, ... but PtrToStructure will create a copy of the reference type in the end. Anyway how would you allocate the array of structures on c++ side so that I can have: "SomeData* ptr" in extern function?

Comment: @John It all depends on who will write on the struct and how many struct you must pass. You can use a `TempStruct[]` as a parameter, if there are multiple elements and the C++ can only read, or the C++ can read and write, but can't change the number of elements (so C# passes 3 elements, the C++ can rewrite the 3 elements, but can't add or remove one of them), or `ref TempStruct`, if there is a single element and the C++ read and write it, or `out TempStruct` if the C++ can only write it, because it is the C++ that is generating it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81362/discussion-between-john-and-xanatos).